# Replacing a dot in an field name

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Good morning,

Working on upgrading to the lastest version of the ELK stack and running into an issue with the field mapping. I have something similar to the following in my raw data:

```
{
  "_index" : "logstash-2016.04.21",
  "level1" : {
    "level2" : {
      "1" : "somevalue",
      "1.1" : "somevalue1"
    }
  }
}
```

And as we all know elasticsearch 2.X does not like dots (.) in field names, messes up the dot-notation. So as a total newbie to elasticsearch, I have not been able to find a way, or search the right terms, to find a way to fix this using mappings or analyzers or 'something i do not yet know about'. I am hoping the community here can help me find a way to fix this so I can re-index all of my current indexes as well as mapping it for future indexes.

Currently on ES version 1.7, running on debian

Thank you,
Mike

Comment: While the logstash plugin might work. I think in my particular situation it isn't. I am trying to go use stream2es to copy from one instance to another. Is there anything directly with elasticsearch (plugin, mapping, template) that might be able to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't fix the input, logstash has a [de_dot](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-de_dot.html) filter for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks @AlainCollins! Pardon my newbie-ness but after installing the plugin, where would I include this to get it to remove the dots?

Comment: Also do you know of a way to use this to reindex existing indexes?

Comment: de_dot is a filter that will, by default, run through all of your fields and remove the dots.  You can configure it to look at some fields.

Comment: How to use the de_dot filter if I am not using log stash? I want to re-index to have a new index with all dots in the fields replaced by an underscore

Comment: @yancheelo try this answer from another contributor?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43120430/elasticsearch-mapping-rename-existing-field