# Elasticsearch Mapping - Rename existing field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

Is there anyway I can rename an element in an existing elasticsearch mapping without having to add a new element ?
If so whats the best way to do it in order to avoid breaking the existing mapping?

e.g. from fieldCamelcase to fieldCamelCase

```
{
    "myType": {
        "properties": {
            "timestamp": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "date_optional_time"
            },
            "fieldCamelcase": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "field_test": {
                "type": "double"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, you can either create a new field or recreate your index

Comment: Of course you can update existing documents!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could do this by creating an [Ingest](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ingest.html) pipeline, that contains a [Rename Processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/rename-processor.html) in combination with the [Reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html).

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/my_rename_pipeline
{
  "description" : "describe pipeline",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "rename": {
        "field": "fieldCamelcase",
        "target_field": "fieldCamelCase"
      }
    }
  ]
}

POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "source"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "dest",
    "pipeline": "my_rename_pipeline"
  }
}
```

Note that you need to be running Elasticsearch 5.x in order to use ingest. If you're running < 5.x then you'll have to go with what @Val mentioned in his comment :)

Comment: What's the syntax for multiple field renaming? Array of objects?

Answer (score 11):

**Updating field name in ES (version>5, missing has been removed) using _update_by_query API:**

Example:

```
POST http://localhost:9200/INDEX_NAME/_update_by_query
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": {
        "must_not": {
            "exists": {
                "field": "NEW_FIELD_NAME"
            }
        }
    }
  },
  "script" : {
    "inline": "ctx._source.NEW_FIELD_NAME = ctx._source.OLD_FIELD_NAME; ctx._source.remove(\"OLD_FIELD_NAME\");"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

First of all, you must understand how **elasticsearch** and **lucene** store data, by immutable segments (you can read about easily on Internet).

So, any solution will remove/create documents and change mapping or create a new index so a new mapping as well.

The easiest way is to use the `update by query` API: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/docs-update-by-query.html

```
POST /XXXX/_update_by_query

{
    "query": { 
    "missing": {
      "field": "fieldCamelCase"
    }
  },
    "script" : {
        "inline": "ctx._source.fieldCamelCase = ctx._source.fieldCamelcase; ctx._source.remove(\"fieldCamelcase\");"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting with ES 6.4 you can use "[Field Aliases](https://www.elastic.co/blog/introducing-field-aliases-in-elasticsearch)", which allow the functionality you're looking for with close to 0 work or resources.

Do note that aliases can only be used for searching - not for indexing new documents.